# Get images from phpmyadmin via image path and view on page

Tags: php, image, path

In my phpmyadmin database I have a table called `rooms` with 2 columns. Column 1 is named `room name` and contains values: `bookstore,foodcourt, etc.` Column 2 is named `images` and contains the path of the image: `/image/bookstore.jpg, /image/foodcourt.jpg, etc.`

**form.php** contains user input such as `bookstore,foodcourt,etc` which is submitted to `image.php`

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="image.php">
    <fieldset>
        <p>Where are you trying to go? </p>
        <input type="text" name="mapinput" id="mapinput">
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**image.php** should match the user input with the database image path and echo the image depending on the user input.

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","Capstone");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['mapinput'])) //mapinput is the user input from the form
{
      $map = $_POST['mapinput']; //user input is assigned variable $map
      $sql = "SELECT images FROM rooms WHERE room name=$map"; //selecting column images from table rooms where room name = user input ($map)
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo  "<img src = 'images" . $row['images'] . "' />"  //images is the column name that holds the image path
  }

}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

When going through, it doesn't post any image from the database image path associated. Any help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: try putting full url `<img src = 'http://yoursite.com/images" . $row['images'] . "' />`

Comment: Wrap $map in single quotes. "SELECT images FROM rooms WHERE room name='$map'"

Comment: @meda the images are just stored in a folder located in /var/www/html/images

Comment: I bet it has to do with permission if you use Ubuntu. Can you show us what mysql fetch array returns here? I mean just print_r to that

Answer (score 0):

It seems a path problem. The best idea is to open up a firebug. Try to inspect your broken image. You will be able to get an idea what is wrong with the path. Once you got the problem add proper URL before **$row['images']**.